# Reputation bug when sorting votes by time

Tags: bug, voting

I've been seeing this voting bug pretty frequently. When viewing `?tab=reputation` tab and sorting by "Time", the upvote score is incorrect.

For example, according to my tab I earned 60 points (6 upvotes, for simplicity) for this recent answer:

[image]

The actual [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76089753/concat-rows-from-two-dataframe-with-muliple-column-with-different-names/76089779#76089779), however, has only 2 upvotes:

[image]

**The discrepancy occurs only when you see the score for the first time** (i.e., the entry is highlighted yellow).

Why is there a discrepancy between the two scores? Its worth nothing that this is only a bug with the "Time" tab. If you sort by Posts, then it correctly records "2 events +20" for the answer above.

Comment: Weird, this is what I see on your reputation page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx8m8.png Maybe one of the cache is out of sync or something.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  thanks for pointing that out, I should have mentioned this occurs when you see that entry for the first time (i.e., the score is highlighted in yellow).

Comment: It's a well-known bug which SE seem to be unable to reproduce and thus fix. Even thought the reproduction steps are simple: it ***ONLY*** shows up when the background is yellow. It's for "new" items. I've compiled all the information I know of it [over at the RPG Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12332). But all this information exists in various places around the network.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/cs95?tab=reputation&StartDate=2023-04-12+07:00:00Z&sort=time) which has a start time added. You'll see a +60 for the post. For whatever reason it decides to calculate it wrong.

Comment: For me that [shows +100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YX0r.png) while the post itself still has 2 upvotes.

Comment: @Marijn yeah, it's different today. I guess it's taking into account more days now or something. Try fiddling with the date in the URL and you'll probably get different results.